# I know that $\exp(\lambda B_{t} -\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t)$ is a martingale, how can I use it to prove that the following are martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion and further let

I know that for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, we have that  $(\exp(\lambda B_{t} -\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t))_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale, but how can I use it to prove that the following are martingales:

$B_{t}^{2}-t,\; \; B_{t}^{3}-3tB_{t}, \; \; B_{t}^{4}-6tB_{t}^2+3t^{2}\; \; (*)$. By differentiating wrt $\lambda $ and then setting $\lambda = 0$, we use that for $s < t$:

$\mathbb E [\exp(\lambda B_{t} -\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t)\lvert \mathcal{F}_{s}]=\exp(\lambda B_{s} -\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}s)$

Now differentiating both sides wrt $\lambda$, and setting $\lambda = 0$ we get:

$\mathbb E[B_{t}\lvert \mathcal{F}_{s}]=B_{s}$ [Side question: What can of justification do I need to bring the differentiation operator of $\lambda$ into the conditional expectation?]

Ok, so now we have the idea to show that $(B_{t})$ is a martingale, but how can we use it to show that $(*)$ are all martingales?

Comment: It will be much easier to check by definition that processes (*) are martingales. Where did you found your problem?

Comment: To prove $f(t,\,B)$ is a martingale, just check $\partial_tf+\tfrac12\partial_B^2f=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exercise from Steele book, Stochastic calculus and financial applications. So firstly note that we can expand $M_t = \exp{(\lambda B_t - (\lambda^2/2)t)}$ as Taylor series in $\lambda$. We have
$$ M_t = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda(B_t - (\lambda/2)t))^{i}}{i!}. $$
Now note that the above expression can be written as
$$ M_t = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{i} H_i(t,B_t), $$
where the $H_i(t,B_t)$ are polynomials. Now for $0 \leq s \leq t$ by martingale property of $M_t$ we have
$$ \mathbb{E}[M_t|\mathcal{F_s}] = M_s, $$
so by series representation
$$ \mathbb{E} \big[\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{i} H_i(t,B_t)|\mathcal{F_s} \big] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{i} H_i(s,B_s). $$
Now one have to justify that expectation and summation above can be interchanged. Then by arbitrariness of $\lambda$ we have that to have equality of coefficients, and this give us $\forall i \geq 0$
$$ \mathbb{E} [H_i(t,B_t)|\mathcal{F_s}] = H_i(s,B_s). $$
To prove that $B^2_t-t,B^3_t−3tB_t,B^4_t−6tB^2_t+3t^2$ are martingales one have to find $H_2, H_3, H_4$ which is the easiest part of this exercise.